# error while running CGAl pacakge examples

Tags: qt, cgal

I'm try to run "map_3_with_colored_facets" example which included in CGAL package
but I faced some errors , it cannot read "Combinatorial_map.h" methods

-cm.make_combinatorial_hexahedron() isn't a member
-  cm.attribute<2> isn't a member
- cm.info<2>  isn't a member ....

```
#include <CGAL/Combinatorial_map.h>
#include <CGAL/Combinatorial_map_constructors.h>
#include <CGAL/Cell_attribute.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <algorithm>
#include <cstdlib>
struct Sum_functor
{
template<class Cell_attribute>
void operator()(Cell_attribute& ca1,Cell_attribute& ca2)
{ ca1.info()=ca1.info()+ca2.info(); }
};

struct Divide_by_two_functor
{
template<class Cell_attribute>
void operator()(Cell_attribute& ca1,Cell_attribute& ca2)
{
ca1.info()=(ca1.info()/2);
ca2.info()=(ca1.info());
}
};
struct Myitem
{
template<class CMap>
struct Dart_wrapper
{
typedef CGAL::Dart<3, CMap> Dart;
typedef CGAL::Cell_attribute<CMap, int, CGAL::Tag_true,
 Sum_functor, Divide_by_two_functor> Facet_attribute;
 typedef CGAL::cpp11::tuple<void,void,Facet_attribute> Attributes;
 };
};
typedef CGAL::Combinatorial_map<3,Myitem> CMap_3;
typedef CMap_3::Dart_handle               Dart_handle;
int main()
{
CMap_3 cm;
// Create 2 hexahedra.
Dart_handle dh1 = cm.make_combinatorial_hexahedron();
Dart_handle dh2 = cm.make_combinatorial_hexahedron();
// 1) Create all 2-attributes and associated them to darts.
for (CMap_3::Dart_range::iterator
   it=cm.darts().begin(), itend=cm.darts().end();
   it!=itend; ++it)
 {
 if ( cm.attribute<2>(it)==NULL )
  cm.set_attribute<2>(it, cm.create_attribute<2>());
 }
 // 2) Set the color of all facets of the first hexahedron to 7.
 for (CMap_3::One_dart_per_incident_cell_range<2, 3>::iterator
   it=cm.one_dart_per_incident_cell<2,3>(dh1).begin(),
   itend=cm.one_dart_per_incident_cell<2,3>(dh1).end(); it!=itend; ++it)
 { cm.info<2>(it)=7; }
 // 3) Set the color of all facets of the second hexahedron to 13.
 for (CMap_3::One_dart_per_incident_cell_range<2, 3>::iterator it=
   cm.one_dart_per_incident_cell<2,3>(dh2).begin(),
   itend=cm.one_dart_per_incident_cell<2,3>(dh2).end(); it!=itend; ++it)
 { cm.info<2>(it)=13; }
 // 4) 3-Sew the two hexahedra along one facet.
 cm.sew<3>(dh1, dh2);
 // 5) Display all the values of 2-attributes.
 for (CMap_3::Attribute_range<2>::type::iterator
   it=cm.attributes<2>().begin(), itend=cm.attributes<2>().end();
   it!=itend; ++it)
  {
   std::cout<<cm.info_of_attribute<2>(it)<<"; ";
 }
std::cout<<std::endl;
// 6) Insert a vertex in the facet between the two hexahedra.
cm.insert_cell_0_in_cell_2(dh2);
// 7) Display all the values of 2-attributes.
for (CMap_3::Attribute_range<2>::type::iterator
   it=cm.attributes<2>().begin(), itend=cm.attributes<2>().end();
   it!=itend; ++it)
{
  std::cout<<cm.info_of_attribute<2>(it)<<"; ";
}
std::cout<<std::endl;
cm.display_characteristics(std::cout);
std::cout<<", valid="<<cm.is_valid()<<std::endl;
return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you mix two different versions of CGAL (perhaps one installed in your system with a package manager, and a local one installed from CGAL repository) ?

If this is the case, I suggest you to remove the version from your system and to use the sources from CGAL git repository (which is generally more up to date).

Comment: how to know that I have more than one version?
"usr/include" path contains one folder "CGAL" andthe folder have no duplicated files

Comment: In a terminal you can use "locate Combinatorial_map.h". How did you install CGAL library ? And how did you install CGAL examples ? If you have only one version of CGAL, one possible problem is that you mix a certain version of CGAL with different versions of CGAL examples.